# Generate PDF using mpdf on ajax call in codeginiter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, mpdf

this question may be the duplicate but I didn't find a valid answer to this type of bug. My code works well without using ajax but gives an error if using ajax.

```
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    $this->data['title']="Sales Report PDF";
    $this->data['description']="Sales report in PDF format";

    $data = $this->get_sales_report_for_pdf();
    $html=$this->load->view('dashboard/sales_report_pdf',$data, true);

    $pdfFilePath ="Salesreport-".time()."-download.pdf";
    $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
```

can anyone know how to work on this ??

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: post the Error please

Comment: FYI, If you are calling the function through ajax it won't work. Because a view will not be loaded through ajax call

Comment: @Anandhunadesh getting parse error

Comment: @AbdullaNilam parse error

Comment: are you trying to convert the current page into pdf? or another page?

Comment: @Anandhunadesh calling ajax from main page, and the page i want to load in pdf is another one

Comment: well in that case I don't think its possible. Because the view you want to load as pdf will not be loaded through ajax call. Try adding window.location in ajax success to call the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use "F" in $pdf->Output();
2. return the file name you saved and in ajax call that url where you saved it.

> ```
> $this->load->library('m_pdf');
> $this->data['title']="Sales Report PDF";
> $this->data['description']="Sales report in PDF format";
>
> $data = $this->get_sales_report_for_pdf();
> $html=$this->load->view('dashboard/sales_report_pdf',$data, true);
>
> $pdfFilePath ="Salesreport-".time()."-download.pdf";
> $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
> $pdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
> $pdf->Output(FCPATH.$pdfFilePath, "F");
> ```

```
return $pdfFilePath;
```

in Ajax response
location.href = YOURPATH.'filename.pdf';

Answer (score 0):

please replace

```
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
```

to

```
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
```

Because `D` is to download and ajax won't provide UI to Download File so Put `F` to save
and Filepath should be valid

```
$pdfFilePath ="Salesreport-".time()."-download.pdf";
```

like

```
$pdfFilePath =FCPATH."upload/Salesreport-".time()."-download.pdf";
```

so it will save into `upload` folder by given name.

Note : **You Can't Download By ajax it will give error.**